# Matching labour costs to a timesheet - rate per person per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having difficulty trying to find the correct rate to use for each employee on a given date.

For each Date, Employee ID and Rate Type, Find the correct Rate Amount. I then need to multiply those two efficiently. The data shown is similar in format to what I'm trying to process in my role.

**Timesheet Format**

```
Date            EmpID   Rate    HoursWorked RateAmount  LabourCost
3/01/2020   JBR001  BR1 8       
10/01/2020  JBR001  BR1 8       
10/01/2020  JBR001  OT1 4       
17/01/2020  JBR001  BR1 8       
24/01/2020  JBR001  BR1 8       
31/01/2020  JBR001  BR1 8       
7/02/2020   JBR001  BR1 8       
14/02/2020  JBR001  BR1 8       
13/03/2020  JBR001  BR1 8       
20/03/2020  JBR001  BR1 8       
20/03/2020  JBR001  OT1 4       
27/03/2020  JBR001  BR1 8       
3/04/2020   JBR001  BR1 8       
17/04/2020  JBR001  BR1 8       
4/01/2020   BJL001  BR1 8       
10/01/2020  BJL001  BR1 8       
27/02/2020  BJL001  BR1 8       
27/02/2020  BJL001  OT1 3       
4/03/2020   BJL001  BR1 8       
10/03/2020  BJL001  BR1 8       
10/03/2020  BJL001  OT1 4       
28/03/2020  BJL001  BR1 8       
3/04/2020   BJL001  BR1 8
```

**Labour Rate Table**

```
EmpID   Rate    RateStart   RateAmount
JBR001  BR1 1/01/2020   10
JBR001  BR1 1/03/2020   11
JBR001  OT1 1/01/2020   15
JBR001  OT1 1/04/2020   16
BJL001  BR1 1/01/2020   12
BJL001  BR1 1/03/2020   13
BJL001  OT1 1/01/2020   15
BJL001  OT1 1/04/2020   16
```

If somebody could advise me how to go about mashing this information together I would be very grateful.
Thank you!

I have been successful in combining this information in PowerQuery/M, but the query was very very slow. I'm hoping somebody could share the power of T-SQL with me!

Comment: 1) Please also show your desired results. 2) Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm trying to identify the correct Rate Amount for each person, on a given day. I tried to join the two tables, but I got as far as the join - similar to - From TimeSheet as TS Left Outer Join LabourRate as LR on TS.EmpID = LR.EmpID AND TS.Rate = LR.Rate AND MAX(TS.Date>=LR.RateStart)

Comment: We don't know what is "correct" for you. It's good pratice to show both sample input data AND also the expected results whenever asking SQL questions to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please add any clarifications, including desired results as tabular data and your attempt, directly into the question.

Comment: Also what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of getting the effective `RateAmount` for a Timesheet entry is a correlated `TOP 1` query ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LJZHS7N-))

```
SELECT TS.*,
       LR.RateAmount
FROM   Timesheet TS
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   LabourRate LR
                    WHERE  TS.EmpId = LR.EmpId
                           AND TS.Rate = LR.Rate
                           AND LR.RateStart <= TS.Date
                    ORDER  BY LR.RateStart DESC) LR
```

The above will need an index on

```
LabourRate(EmpId,Rate,RateStart) INCLUDE ( RateAmount)
```

If the tables aren't too large the above will likely be adequate - though there are other potentially more efficient ways.

If you are on SQL Server 2022 the `IGNORE NULLS` option to `LAST_VALUE` could also potentially be useful here to keep track of the effective rate without needing a correlated query ([Fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJqfoQJh))

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT 1 AS Code, [Date], EmpId, Rate, HoursWorked, NULL AS RateAmount
FROM   Timesheet
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS Code, [RateStart],[EmpId], [Rate], NULL, RateAmount
FROM LabourRate
), T2 AS
(
SELECT *, 
       EffectiveRateAmount = LAST_VALUE(RateAmount) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId, Rate ORDER BY [Date], Code)
FROM T1
)
SELECT [Date], EmpId, Rate, HoursWorked, EffectiveRateAmount
FROM T2
WHERE Code = 1
```

Comment: Great minds ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ...)` pattern to select the appropriate rate amount for each timesheet record. A `CROSS APPLY` is like a join to a subquery, where that subquery can reference tables earlier in the `FROM` clause.

In your case, it appears that you need to match on `EmpID` and `Rate`, and then select the latest Labour Rate Table row with a RateStart value equal or less than the timesheet date.

This can be done as follows:

```
SELECT T.*, R.RateAmount, T.HoursWorked * R.RateAmount AS LabourCost
FROM TimeSheet T
OUTER APPLY (
    -- Most recent rate as of timesheet date
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM LabourRateTable R
    WHERE R.EmpID = T.EmpID
    AND R.Rate = T.Rate
    AND R.RateStart <= T.Date
    ORDER BY R.RateStart DESC
) R
ORDER BY T.EmpID, T.Date
```

Note that I used an `OUTER APPLY` instead of a `CROSS APPLY`. An outer apply is like a left join variant of a cross apply. If no match is found, it will still return a result having null RateAmount value (and null calculated LabourCost). This should not occur if your data is good, but returning null values may be preferred over quietly discarding unmatched data.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rb9pr7gQ) for a demo.

Sample results:

| Date | EmpID | Rate | HoursWorked | RateAmount | LabourCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-04 | BJL001 | BR1 | 8 | 12 | 96 |
| 2020-01-10 | BJL001 | BR1 | 8 | 12 | 96 |
| 2020-02-27 | BJL001 | BR1 | 8 | 12 | 96 |
| 2020-02-27 | BJL001 | OT1 | 3 | 15 | 45 |
| 2020-03-04 | BJL001 | BR1 | 8 | 13 | 104 |
| 2020-03-10 | BJL001 | BR1 | 8 | 13 | 104 |
| 2020-03-10 | BJL001 | OT1 | 4 | 15 | 60 |
| 2020-03-28 | BJL001 | BR1 | 8 | 13 | 104 |
| 2020-04-03 | BJL001 | BR1 | 8 | 13 | 104 |
| 2020-01-03 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 10 | 80 |
| 2020-01-10 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 10 | 80 |
| 2020-01-10 | JBR001 | OT1 | 4 | 15 | 60 |
| 2020-01-17 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 10 | 80 |
| 2020-01-24 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 10 | 80 |
| 2020-01-31 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 10 | 80 |
| 2020-02-07 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 10 | 80 |
| 2020-02-14 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 10 | 80 |
| 2020-03-13 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 11 | 88 |
| 2020-03-20 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 11 | 88 |
| 2020-03-20 | JBR001 | OT1 | 4 | 15 | 60 |
| 2020-03-27 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 11 | 88 |
| 2020-04-03 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 11 | 88 |
| 2020-04-17 | JBR001 | BR1 | 8 | 11 | 88 |